# La estructura IF no me funciona como creo que deberia [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, condiciones

Tengo esta función:

```
var arrayGuardado = new Array();var contador = 0;
var tranca = 17;
var suma = 1
```

/*Esta función marcha sin problemas, convierte un numero ingresado por el usuario a un numero hexadecimal y decimal*/

```
function hexAdec() {
var hexaAdeci = parseInt(document.getElementById("textoCalculadora").value);

var convertido = hexaAdeci.toString(16);
document.getElementById("numeroHexadecimal").innerHTML = convertido;

var deciAhexa = parseInt(document.getElementById("textoCalculadora").value);
var convertido2 = deciAhexa.toString(10);
document.getElementById("numeroDecimal").innerHTML = convertido2;
```

}

/*Esta función no funciona bien*/

```
function guardarhexa(contador , convertido , arrayGuardado , suma , tranca){ 
if (contador < tranca){
    /*TENDRIA QUE ESCRIBIR ESTE MENSAJE*/
    arrayGuardado.push(convertido2);
    alert("Dato ingresado exitosamente");
}else{
    /*PERO ESCRIBE ESTE MENSAJE*/
    alert("Todas las casillas están llenas");
}
var contador = contador + suma;
```

}

Comment: Si pasas las variables como parámetro estas clonando las variables originales, no son referencias y están solo incluidas en el contexto de la nueva función, es como si crearás las variables dentro de la misma. Si quieres editar un dato global, deberías solo usar las variables globales que ya tienes o crear un state, con una clase o estructura similar.

Comment: Varias anotaciones, crear un array con su constructor es mala práctica, solo [] es mejor, usar var es mala práctica, ya que puede generar errores de contexto y herencia, a de más no es explícita y menos, optimizada, usar else cuando no es necesario es mala práctica y por último trata de no hacer varias referencias a algo si ya lo tienes, como el elemento de la calculadora, lo pides varias veces pero el valor no cambia en la misma ejecución de la función, solo usa la variable que ya tienes, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Primero, tienes que observar que realmente el if se hace con los valores que le pasas a la función y no con los generales de la clase.

Si al llamar la función la llamas tal que :
`guardarHexa(0,null,null,1,5)` 
va a devolver un valor distinto a si la llamas
`guardarHexa(0,null,null,1,0)`

Igualmente, si ves que no sabes por donde coger el problema porque te recomendaría que hicieras un alert antes de empezar el if para comprobar el valor de ambas variables, y así saber de donde vienen.

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda, si no tienes algo claro de esta respuesta, estaría encantado de que me respondas y así poder ayudar más, un saludo

Comment: Me sirvió al final, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Nada, a cuidarse!!